# UI handling according to Multiple language With out Autolayouts

Tags: ios, localization

I have two languages in my application which are English and Arabic.

How do I change the UI according to the selected Language With out Autolayouts?

For example:

- If the user selects `English` we have to display text left to right.
- If the user selects `Arabic` we have to display the text right to left.

The display rules includes Tableviews, Labels, Buttons, Images, Collection views, Views, Textfields, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> There are lot of scenarios you need to consider while working for
>   app which is changing the UI within app for Arabic.    I used following
>   code. This will work perfectly. You need to handle it properly for
>   scrollView and UITableView.    Need to be sure that UI is proper while pushing and
>   poping from view controllers.

```
- (void)reloadUI {

  if (languageIsChanged == YES) {

     [self reloadRTLView:self.view];
  }
}


  - (void)reloadRTLView:(UIView *)view {

    [self changeViewRTL:view];
    for (UIView *tempView in view.subviews) {

        [self reloadRTLView:tempView];
    }
}

- (void)changeViewRTL:(UIView*)tempView {

    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constrain in tempView.constraints) {

        NSLayoutAttribute firstAttribute = constrain.firstAttribute;
        NSLayoutAttribute secondAttribute = constrain.secondAttribute;

        if ((firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading || firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing) && (secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading || secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing)) {

            if (firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) {
                firstAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeTrailing;
            } else if (firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing) {
                firstAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeLeading;
            }

            if (secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) {
                secondAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeTrailing;
            } else if (secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing) {
                secondAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeLeading;
            }

            constrain.constant *= -1;
            NSLayoutConstraint *constrainNew =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:constrain.firstItem attribute:firstAttribute relatedBy:constrain.relation toItem:constrain.secondItem attribute:secondAttribute multiplier:constrain.multiplier constant:constrain.constant];
            [tempView removeConstraint:constrain];
            [tempView addConstraint:constrainNew];
        }
    }
}
```

Up vote if this help you.

Answer (score 0):

In swift we can use `UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft` for Right to left(Arabic).